# Golang/mgo : How can I store Date (not ISODate) in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo, isodate

If I store current time like this:

```
type Test struct {
    Id string `bson:"id" json:"id,omitempty"`
    TestTime time.Time `bson:"testTime" json:"testTime,omitempty"`
}
...

t := Test {
    Id : "TEST0001",
    TestTime : time.Now(),
}
...

c.Insert(t)
```

Then I use mongochef to search it :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("576bc7a48114a14b47920d60"), 
    "id" : "TEST0001", 
    "testTime" : ISODate("2016-06-23T11:27:30.447+0000")
}
```

So, mgo store ISODate by default, how can I store Date not ISODate ?

Answer (score 2):

mgo automagically converts `time.Time` into a Mongo internal date data type ([source](https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/blob/v2-unstable/bson/encode.go#L43-L57), actually it's just a timestamp with no timezone info and it's always corrected to UTC). Any other functionaly has to be manually implemented by you.

You can force mgo to correctly (de)serialize your types by implementing the [Getter](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#Getter) and [Setter](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#Setter) interfaces from package `mgo/bson` thought it's pretty low-level so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a custom struct that saves the timezone like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/A0n6DGBAqt).

The you can define a custom `Unmarshal` that changes the location of the date on loading.

```
func (t *TimeWithTimezone) Unmarshal(in []byte, out interface{}) (err error) {
    type decode TimeWithTimezone
    var d decode
    if err := bson.NewDecoder(in).Decode(&d); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    loc, err := FixedZone(d.Timezone, d.Timezone)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Invalid Timezone: %s", d.Timezone)
    }
    t.Time = d.Time.In(loc)
    t.Timezone = d.Timezone
    return nil
}
```

Something like this should do the trick, it's not tested, just to give you an idea!